# java.io.eofexception

Tags: android

What does this error mean?

Below is my logcat output:

```
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339): java.io.EOFException
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:544)
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:784)
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
01-23 17:09:29.120: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at com.sfcca.coverflow.Store$downloadMagazine.doInBackground(Store.java:881)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at com.sfcca.coverflow.Store$downloadMagazine.doInBackground(Store.java:1)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-23 17:09:29.130: W/System.err(24339):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

According to the logcat this is the part of the code whereby there's an error:
I'm trying to retrieve image url from a server then download them

```
try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                    Log.i("im connected", "Download");
                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                    File filename;
                    try {
                         // GET EXTERNAL STORAGE, SAVE FILE THERE
                        File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Futsing/issue"+issueNumber+"/");
                        storagePath.mkdirs();

                        filename = new File(storagePath + "/page"+number+".jpg");
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                        bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(),
                                filename.getName());          


                         // displayImage();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try from this [Android HttpsUrlConnection eofexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411213/android-httpsurlconnection-eofexception)

Looks like you need to add

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) { urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was the network connection that I was using for uploading the file. After switching the network connection(to my LAN wifi network) everything worked.
I was testing it on my local server and was trying to upload the file using external network connection other then my LAN network.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

EOFException means End Of File (EOF) Exception. EOF is used to indicate end of a file. Normally if you want to read a file till the end you perform a while operation with condition EOF has not reached.

It is somewhat similar to the '/0' present at end of string. EOF is instead used to mark the end of file

You might be trying to read the file after EOF has reached that will cause exception to be raised

Comment: How do I solve the issue? Sometime it doesn't occur, sometimes it does. I am confused!