# facebook android SDK java.io.EOFException after a few calls

Tags: java, android, facebook

Anyone have experience or seen this particular issue??

After a few calls facebook android sdk to make posting to a group,

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", deviceName);
params.putString("link", link.url);

Request req = new Request(session, "/" + groupId + "/feed", params,
                        HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
```

I encounter errors continually until I exit and relaunch android app. Exception being thrown is:

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: java.io.EOFException
at com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(Response.java:333)
at com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(Request.java:1553)
at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1452)
....
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
```

Looks very similar to a few issues I've seen, like [java.io.eofexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476024/java-io-eofexception). I'm new to facebook android sdk as far as I can tell I have no access to the underlying http connection where I could probably address the issue.

Anyone have any experience here with this kind of error (on the facebook platform with their android sdk)??

Thanks,
Ray.

Comment: Apologies, nvm. I have no idea why I didn't realize that the facebook android sdk is built when your android application is being built. Just made a few changes to the url connection initialization in facebook sdk and (fingers crossed) will address issue.

Comment: I am also getting this Exception sometimes.Have you got any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The EOF exception must be a bug in the FB API's, not handling certain response types correctly. But the actual cause of the misleading EOF error could be a bug in your code.

I ended up scouring through my code and found a few bugs when enabling and disabling share setting in my app. There where certain circumstances that my settings were set to "Share enabled" I.e. post to users timeline. But actually, the app never correctly obtained the "publish_actions" permission, or it has since been revoked by the user. So I had a valid FB session, but was attempting to post to the users timeline when I never had the correct permissions in my session, and in that cause I always seemed to get the EOF error. Hence I say perhaps there's a bug in the FB API's, it should give a proper 401 or 403 permissions type response.

So in short, make sure you do actually have the correct publish permissions before attempting to post to the timeline. (I also had an issue when upgrading the API, "publish_stream" seems to have been renamed to "publish_actions", you may want to check that too(although I think the error for that is more obvious).

So far this has worked for me. Good luck.